# Cannot assign value for column in pandas DataFrame using another column's value as Series' key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Consider a trivial example with a Dataframe `df` and a Series `s`

```
import pandas as pd

matching_vals = range(20,30)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'], index=range(0,10))
df['a'] = matching_vals
s  = pd.Series(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), index=matching_vals)

df['b'] = s[df['a']]
```

At this point I would expect `df['b']` to contain the letters `A` through `J`, but instead it's all `NaN`. However, if I replace the last line with

```
n = df['a'][2]
df['c'] = s[n]
```

then `df['c']` is filled with `C`s, as I'd expect, so I'm pretty sure it's not some strange type error.

I'm new to pandas, and this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s[df['a']]` has an index which is different than `df`'s index:

```
In [104]: s[df['a']]
Out[104]: 
a
20    A
21    B
22    C
23    D
24    E
25    F
26    G
27    H
28    I
29    J
```

When you assign a Series to a column of a DataFrame, Pandas tries to assign values according to the index. Since `s[df['a']]` does not have any values associated with the indices of `df`, `NaN` values are assigned. The assignment does not add new rows to `df`.

If you don't want the index to enter into the assignment, you could use

```
df['b'] = s[df['a']].values
```

---

For a demonstration of the matching of indices, notice how

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'], index=range(0,10))
df['a'] = range(0,10)[::-1]
s  = pd.Series(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), index=range(0,10)[::-1])
df['b'] = s[df['a']]
```

yields

```
In [123]: s[df['a']]
Out[123]: 
a
9    A
8    B
7    C
6    D
5    E
4    F
3    G
2    H
1    I
0    J
dtype: object

In [124]: df
Out[124]: 
   a  b
0  9  J
1  8  I
2  7  H
3  6  G
4  5  F
5  4  E
6  3  D
7  2  C
8  1  B
9  0  A

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

The values of `df['b']` are "flipped" to make the indices match.